# Sending message to specific channel based on an argument

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I have searched up and found multiple forum posts on both Reddit and StackOverflow where users are asking how to send a message to the specific channel, but I cannot find one where you can send to a specific channel using an Argument. What I mean is that you use

```
return bot.channels.get(channel).send(embed);
```

I have been testing around with this "function" and have managed to send the message to a specific channel, but it also includes the arg[0] aka the channel id. The command is

```
announce "CHANNEL ID" "MESSAGE"
```

It does send the embed with the message to that specific channel I input, but It adds the `CHANNEL ID` to the embed, so I tried to use `arg[0]` in the embed's `.setDescription(arg[0])` but it didn't work. It spat out an error message to me which I have no idea what means. But maybe one if you pro's out there know what I can do. Here is the entire command Code:

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}announce`) {
  console.log(message.author.username + " executed an Announcement in the channel #" + message.channel.name);
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("#e56b00")
    .setAuthor("Announcement from " + message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
    .setDescription(arg)
    .setFooter(message.author.username)
    .setTimestamp();

  return bot.channels.get(channel).send(embed);
}
```

And here is the error code. Note that the error only pops up when I put `arg[0]` in the `.setDescription()` part of the embed. The channel let works fine with `arg[1]`

```
(node:7900) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Client.bot.on (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Discord Bots\DISCORDBOSS.js\index.js:32:34)
    at Client.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Discord Bots\DISCORDBOSS.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Discord Bots\DISCORDBOSS.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Discord Bots\DISCORDBOSS.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Discord Bots\DISCORDBOSS.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Discord Bots\DISCORDBOSS.js\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Receiver._receiver.onmessage (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Discord Bots\DISCORDBOSS.js\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:137:47)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Discord Bots\DISCORDBOSS.js\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:409:14)
(node:7900) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7900) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: I tried, didn't let me use the code format. It just bugged out. Thanks I also need to add: https://pastebin.com/SKfe2f9g

Comment: Thank you George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `message.mentions` property. So you would do the following:

`let announceChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();`

Then to send the message do the following;
`message.guild.channels.find(t => t.id == announceChannel.id).send(myMessage);`

Comment: Will this let me get the channel by using #channel_name? Instead of ID? If not how would I do so? Also I will try the code once I get home.

Comment: @Marius Yes, A channel mention is #channel_name. So instead of having to copy the ID you can just mention the channel.

Comment: Thank you for the code. The code works fine now. However, it still displays the #channel_name in front of the argument I provide. So when the announcement displays on the channel I selected it looks like this:

Announcement from Marius H.
#testing-channel-please-mute This is a test

Comment: Nevermind! I got it working with some magic :D Thank you either way. 
Here is the working code:
let taggedChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
  let specifiedchannel = message.guild.channels.find(t => t.id == taggedChannel.id);;
  console.log ("The announcement was sent to " + specifiedchannel);
  if(!specifiedchannel) return message.channel.send("That channel does not exist!");

  message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
  specifiedchannel.send(embed);
  console.log (message.author.username + " executed an Announcement in the channel #" + message.channel.name);